# Ubuntu 18.04/GNOME software folder groups don't get respected in Show All Applications

Tags: 18.04, software-center, gnome-shell

I am using the default folder groups within Ubuntu/GNOME software center, Utilities and Sundry.

I have noticed Terminal is marked as a utility yet this appears directly in **Show Applications** > **All Applications** rather than in the folder Utilities, why?

In effect this stops me from organizing apps as I would like. Where do these overriding rules exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because the "app folder" named **Utilities** is not associated to the "*Utilities*" category. By default the Utilities app folder is associated to only the "*X-GNOME-Utilities*" category.

So in order to move Terminal into the *Utilities* app-folder, you may add *X-GNOME-Utilities* category to the `Categories=` line of the `.desktop` file associated to the Terminal application.

An arguably simpler and user-friendly way would be using a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called  "[Appfolders Management extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1217/appfolders-manager/)". This extension provides

> An easy way to manage "appfolders" (folders in the applications view) directly from the applications view.

Right click on an app icon and you'll get the options to add or remove the app from certain app-folder(s) and create new app-folders.

[image]

You can also right click on an app-folder and associate categories to the app-folder.

Comment: Thanks - on second thoughts... i've removed ALL the folders - thats a much better preference for me anyway.